# Node Js html css

Tags: html, css, node.js

****Css File Cannot connect with the below****

it is in the flow of
root

/index.html

/server.js

/css/style.css

**My /server.js Code**

```js
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
        throw err; 
    }       
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(8000);
});
```

```css
**CSS css/style.css**

   .raj{
    background-color: red;
   }
```

```html
**html /index.html**

<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" /> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<span class="raj">
asldfasd <br/>
fasd <br/>
fas <br/>
dfa <br/>
sdf <br/>
sadf <br/>
asd <br/>
fas <br/>
df <br/>
sad <br/>
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

css cannot connect with this above html file

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by your web server not checking the path of the URL request but is rather going to return the same HTML file no mater the path or file extension you use. To get around this shortcoming of the node http module I would recommend utilizing a framework such as express.js
Or if you only want to serve static files I would recommend you use http-server, you can install it using the following command:

```
npm install http-server -g
```

After installation you can navigate to the folder you store your html and CSS files in then run your webserver using the following command:

```
http-server
```

You can read more about the module [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)

Comment: if you have any sample please attach

Comment: Rather than the node http try a lightweight mod like https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-static

Comment: @VigneshSathiyanarayanan I've edited in an example

Answer (score -1):

Just Replace this line of code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
```

with this,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" />
```